# Share a method with all controllers : Best practice

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a notification system in symfony2 and I need to get the notifications for every page I'm running.
the trivial solution is to copy the content of the function in every controller and call the function from `$this`.
How can I make the notification function accessible for every controller? I heard that setting a controller as service is bad practice. what's the best practice then ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to show notifications on every page, as in in the template?

Comment: I meant to get the notifications data on every controller

Comment: Why is it that the notification data is needed in each controller? Why not just use a service that handles the notification and call that using `$this-container->get('notifications.service')`?

Comment: That was exactly my question. I thought services were bad practice

Comment: Services are what the whole framework is built on. Apparently controllers as services are a bad idea but services, in general, are what you should be doing all of your business logic in. Your controller is only really there to call the services that handle everything (router, templating, etc) and output their results.... I still don't understand why the notifications are needed in every controller though. Are you wanting to actually process the notifications in each controller or just to output them to your template?

Comment: Just for output purposes

Comment: Then the best thing would be to use a twig extension. I've added an answer.

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer

Comment: I know it's off topic but where did the notion that controllers as services is a bad idea come from?

Comment: I read it longtime ago, from Fabian the owner of symfony2

Comment: I suspect you may have read it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If just using it for output in the template then best approach would be to use a custom `TwigFunction` and then calling that in a base/layout/extended template like so..

TwigExtension

```
namespace Acme\NotificationBundle\Twig;

use Acme\NotificationBundle\Provider\NotificationProviderInterface;

class AcmeNotificationExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $container;
    protected $notificationProvider;

    public function __construct(
        ContainerInterface $container,
        NotificationProviderInterface $notificationProvider
    )
    {
        $this->notificationProvider = $notificationProvider;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
                'acme_render_notifications', 
                array($this, 'renderNotifications')
            ),
        );
    }

    public function renderNotification($template = 'default:template.html.twig')
    {
        $notifications = $this->notificationsProvider->getCurrentNotifications();
                         // Or whatever method provides your notifications

        return $this->container->get('templating')->render(
            $template,
            array('notifications' => $notifications)
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_notification_extension';
    }
}
```

Services

```
parameters:
    acme.twig.notification_extension.class: 
                    Acme\NotificationBundle\Twig\AcmeNotificationExtension

services:
    acme.twig.notification_extension:
        class: %acme.twig.notification_extension.class%
        arguments:
            - @service_container
            - @acme.provider.notifcation
              // Or what ever your notification provider service is named
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

This way you would be able to call your notifications in any template using `acme_render_notifications()` (with the default template) or `acme_render_notifications('AcmeOtherBundle:Notifications:in_depth.html.twig')` (with a different template if needed) and your controller aren't even touched.

If it was put in a parent template in a block like ..

```
{% block notifications %}
    {{ acme_render_notifications() }}
{% endblock notifications %}
```

..then it would run on every page unless you had overridden the block in your child class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I will sure have plenty of questions to ask about this solution because this is the first time I face such as approach!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, and I think it is among the best practices, is setting up a service with the function then just instantiate it in each controller.

Comment: I think Fabian, the owner of symfony2 said it is bad practice to set the controller as service.. I'm not sure though , but I read it somewhere in the past

Comment: Well it wouldn't be setting the controller as service per say. It would be setting the specific function as a service then calling this service in your controllers.

Comment: After documentation reviews , it seems that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt its bad practice, 
Many solutions are possible, Here we will discuss on abstract level

- A global utility can be used with different scopes (application, session scope) depending upon the requirements
- Make this utility accessible to all available controllers

Comment: How about making the utility accessible to all controllers? it's the services right?

Comment: Its a mechanism on which most of the communication (notification, messaging) servers works like jmf, red5, jmx etc.
A utility may be a simple class having the application scope which receives the notification from whole clients (pages) and managing them on their session bases.